# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No directory at file how to solve this

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

> Error occures

[error massage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBY2s.png)

[Error massage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q97q.png)

,,,

> Properties file

[picture of properties file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1lYF.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Kindly read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and modify your question.

Comment: The driver letter is missing the colon.

Comment: Let's try with the path: file:///c/Users/aadpatil/git-localconfig-repo without configrepo